# Why value not same even call same variable

Tags: android, arrays, string, integer

```
    //global 

    getDatabaseChart();
    addData();


public void addData() {
    int a;
    a = profile.getTotalBelum();
    Log.d("AA",""+a);
    final float[] yData = {a};
    ......
 }

    public void getDatabaseChart(){
    //Creating a string request
    Log.d("MasukTak","MasukTak");
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.URL_WEB + "a.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //   hidePDialog();
                    try {

                        Log.d("TgkSini", response);
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                        int success = json.getInt("success");

                        if (success == 1) {
                            user = json.getJSONArray("user");

                            for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject obj = user.getJSONObject(i);

                                profile = new ProfileUser();
                                profile.setTotalBelum(obj.getInt("belum"));


                             Log.d("BelumB",String.valueOf(profile.getTotalBelum()));

                            }
                            abc = profile.getTotalBelum();
                            Log.d("abccc", String.valueOf(abc));


                        } else {
                            Log.d("data2 ", "no user");
                        } ...............
```

This my code .. Now i change code .. I just direct integer value .. when i see logcat .. check log.d abccc .. value for abc = 2 ... then i check log.d AA value for a = 0 ...

How to solve it ? Please help me.

Comment: I just compiled your code, it is working fine. Can you check which line the error is occurring?

Comment: Don't just log only `a`, Log all and post the full stracktrace !

Comment: @NecipAllef ... yes it working fine but the value that i get not same .. huhu

Answer (score 1):

if you try to parse it to integer.

Check before parsing. or handle Exception properly.
for example:

```
try{
   int a = Integer.parseInt(profile.getTotalBelum());
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
```

...
    }

Comment: Sir @damini mehra .. i updated my question .. actually , i still got not same value .. so i directly call integer .. but still not get same value .. Can you see my updated question..

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to handle the exception:

```
public static int parseInt(String number, int defaultValue){
    try{
       return Integer.parseInt(number);
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
       return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

This is how to use that method:

```
a = parseInt(profile.getTotalBelum(), 3);
// if the string cannot be converted to integer,
// the value will be returned to 3 (i.e. the defaultValue)
```

Comment: Sir @Anggrayudi H.. i updated my question .. actually , i still got not same value .. so i directly call integer .. but still not get same value .. Can you see my updated question..

Answer (score 0):

Check below updated method,

```
 public void addData() 
 {

    a = convertData(profile.getTotalBelum().toString());
    Log.d("AAAA",""+a);
    aa = convertData(profile.getTotalSedang().toString());
    aaa = convertData(profile.getTotalLulus().toString());

    float[] yData = { a, aa, aaa};
 }

 public int convertData(String strTemp)
 {
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        i = Integer.parseInt(strTemp);            
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         i = 0;
    }

    return i;
 }
```

Comment: Sir @Vickyexpert.. i updated my question .. actually , i still got not same value .. so i directly call integer .. but still not get same value .. Can you see my updated question..